# What is the correct approach for the following question?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

From a group of $7$ persons, $7$ committees are formed. Any $2$ committees have exactly $1$ member in common. Each person is in exactly $3$ committees.

1. At least $1$ committee must have more than $3$ members;
2. Each committee must have exactly $3$ members;
3. Each committee must have more than $3$ members;
4. Nothing can be said about the sizes of the committees.

I used block designs. Using which I could prove that it is not possible for a committee to have 4 members .Which lead to me the answer that each committee must have exactly 3 members. However, I was looking to see if there existed a more formal approach for solving this.

My approach was just in case there are four members in the committee then they should each be in two more committees . If none of the two are in the same committee then this makes the number of committees to be 9. That will be in contradiction just seven committees existing . Hence there should be some committees such that two participants of the original four membered committee belong in them . Hence we come at a contradiction again.

Comment: What are your ideas? Did you do block designs?

Comment: I did , do the block designs . Using which I could prove that it is not possible for a committee to have 4 members .Which lead to me the answer that each committee must have exactly 3 members. 

However, I was looking to see if there existed a more formal approach for solving this.

Comment: 4 members or more than 4 members too?

Comment: My approach was just in case there are four members in the committee then they should each be in two more committees . If none of the two are in the same committee then this makes the number of committees to be 9.

That will be in contradiction just seven committees existing . Hence there should be some committees such that two participants of the original four membered committee belong in them . Hence we come at a contradiction again.

Comment: So you already ruled out (a) and (c) using this reasoning. Add it to the question! It shows work done. Also, you ruled out (d) as well, come to think of it.

Comment: But i was wondering if my method is rigorous enough ?

Or if there is a way for us to put the same reasoning in a more concise mathematical way.

Comment: I think your reasoning is fine. If you're allowed to just give the answer, give it, otherwise add the reasoning you gave

Comment: What is a block design ?

Comment: @user230452 read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_design

Comment: I added the information you included in the comments about your approach.  It should be included in the statement of the problem so that you receive responses that address the specific difficulties you are encountering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To move the remarks to an answer: suppose some committee $c$ has at least $4$ different members $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4$ from $\{1,\ldots,7\}$.

Then $x_i$ is also in two other committees, say $c^1_i, c^2_i$, where $c^1_i \neq c^2_i$ and $c^1_i \neq c, c^2_i \neq c$, for $i=1,\ldots,4$.

The set $\{c\} \cup \{c^j_i: i=1,\ldots,4; j=1,2\}$ has at most 7 members so the second set has coinciding members: there are $j,i,j',i'$ such that $c^j_i = c^{j'}_{i'} = c'$. We know that $i \neq i'$ and so we have that both $c$ and $c'$ have the members $x_i$ and $x_{i'}$ in common. This contradicts the assumptions.

(argument from OP, made a bit more formal).

This shows that (1) is false, no member can have more than 3 members. 3 is even more false, and 4 is false (we just said something about the size of the committees and proved it to boot). So 2 must be true by elimination.

Now find a block design on 7 points to show it is even possible to do it.